# Resolving multiple promises using Protractor, Cucumber, Chai as Promised

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, chai, cucumberjs

I'm in the need to assert the number of the children `.row` of a series of divs `.container` is greater than 0.

```
this.Then(/^I should see at least one element in each container$/, function (done) {  
    page.element.all(by.css('.container'))                                                    
        .each(function (element, index) {                                     
            element.all(by.css('.row'))                               
                .then(function(elements) {                                        
                    expect(elements.length).to.be.greaterThan(0);                   
                    done();                                                       
                });                                                               
    });
});
```

The markup looks like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

and there must be at least one `.row` in each container.

The problem is that it always passes, as soon as the first checks true.

I've tried different solutions using `protractor.promise` object, also trying to save the promise within the `each` iteration and then trying to do the expectation at the end but nothing really worked.

I've started thinking that I should take this approach from a completely different perspective.

Any takers?

Comment: Are those rows under div's? I mean one div has many rows, something like that?

Comment: @GirishSortur added markup definition.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting the row elements under each div and then assert if there are more than zero rows in each div. Try this -

```
this.Then(/^I should see at least one element in each container$/, function () {  
    page.element.all(by.css('.container'))                                                    
        .each(function (ele, index) {                                     
            ele.$$('.row')     // get all the row elements in each div                           
                .then(function(elements) {                                        
                    expect(elements.length).to.be.greaterThan(0);                                                                         
                });                                                               
    });
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I thought that `ele.$$('.row')` is effectively the same as `ele.all(by.css('.row'))` :-/ unfortunately it still exits as long as the first `expect` returns true.

Comment: OK, seen your last edit which removed the `done()` call. I now get `AssertionError: expected 1 to be above 1`

Comment: I guess that's because you have only 1 row in the second div. Can you tell me where is this error coming up from? I mean is it for the first div with 3 rows or second div with 1 row. And your expect error looks like you are expecting something to be greaterThan(1).

Comment: I'm testing this with 11 and 12 rows in each container. That's why this to me doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: OUCH, found out the error I was looking at was coming from a typo. Now, without the `done()` I get: `BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining`

Comment: And what happens if you put in `done()` call at the end? I guess you should put done() when all your expectations are complete ouside `element.all()` not sure if it helps.

Comment: so I do see the tests passing, but I don't know whether it's just passing because it goes straight to `done()` or what. If I `console.log(elements.length)` I do get both printed, so it might actually be it... I don't know much of what's behind it.